# Phalcon won't register parsedown class

Tags: php, class, classloader, phalcon

```
$loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();
$loader->registerNamespaces(
array(
   "Sabberworm"         => "app/core/Sabberworm/",
   "Parsedown"         => "app/core/Parsedown/",
))->register();
```

Now if i initialize Parsedown() class with

```
$parser = new Parsedown\Parsedown();
```

I'm getting:

```
   Fatal error: Class 'Parsedown\Parsedown' not found
```

But Sabberworm works fine:

```
$loader = new Sabberworm\CSS\Parser();
```

My folder structure:

```
/app/
/app/core/
/app/core/Sabberworm/CSS/Parser.php
/app/core/Parser/Parsedown.php
```

Why Parsedown doesn't work with Universal loader?

If i use something like this:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
require preg_replace('{\\\\|_(?!.*\\\\)}', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, ltrim($class, '\\')).'.php';
});
```

It works. But i want to use universal loader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();
$loader->registerNamespaces(
array(
 "Sabberworm"         => "app/core/Sabberworm/",
 "Parsedown"         => "app/core/Parser/", //Now is right
))->register();

$parser = new Parser\Parsedown(); //now it works
```